# JQuery border animation Chrome & Firefox issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, firefox, google-chrome, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to use JQuery for color animation (with jquery-ui and jquery.color). It works fine for backgroundColor

```
function t1() {
    $('#i1').animate({backgroundColor: '#0f0'}, 1000, t2);
    //$('#i1').animate({borderColor: '#0f0'}, 1000, t2);
}
function t2() {
    $('#i1').animate({backgroundColor: '#00f'}, 1000, t1);
    //$('#i1').animate({borderColor: '#00f'}, 1000, t1);
}

t1();
```

But the same code doesn't work correctly for borderColor (seems like jquery resets color to #fff before each animation).

Demo (i want border and background to be the same color): http://jsfiddle.net/xqCNx/

Comment: works for me, even in slow motion can't see the white reset - http://jsfiddle.net/xqCNx/1/

Comment: @Zoltan Toth I can, I'm using chrome. This may be a browser-based problem?

Comment: @SomekidwithHTML seems like browser-based. It's ok in safari, but doesn't work in firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is easy. Just use borderLeftColor, borderRightColor, borderTopColor, borderBottomColor instead of borderColor.